# Datatable - Late bound Resolution; runtime errors could occur

Tags: vb.net

I have some code in my application that loops through rows in a datatable. I am getting a log of warnings "Late Bound resolution; runtime errors could occur" I was wondering if anyone had any suggestions on how to clear them up.

```
For Each row In dt.Rows
    RowCount += 1
    If row("SelfRating") IsNot DBNull.Value Then
        If row("SelfRating") > 0 Then
            EmployeeCompletedRows += 1
        End If
    End If
    If row("ManagerRating") IsNot DBNull.Value Then
        If row("ManagerRating") > 0 Then
            ManagerCompletedRows += 1
        End If
    End If
Next
```

Answer (score 0):

An object is assigned to a variable declared to be of the Object Data Type is the reason.

When you declare a variable as Object, the compiler must perform late binding, which causes extra operations at run time. It also exposes your application to potential run-time errors. If you declare the variable to be of a specific type, the compiler can perform early binding at compile time. This results in improved performance, controlled access to the members of the specific type, and better readability of your code.

Also by default, this message should be a warning.

With out showing your variables and their types it is hard to say except your for loop is not specifying what `row` is... this could be the problem

Try this...

```
 For Each row As DataRow In dt.Rows...
```

Here I am specifying the object type upfront which isnt late binding...

Also turn `Option Strict On` its a great friend to have.

Comment: With `Option Infer On` the row iterator would be cast as `DataRow`.  `row("SelfRating")` however would always be `Object`, so an expression like `row("SelfRating") > 0` would generate the warning.

Comment: I would agree but then again I want the compiler to throw up when there is a problem... not rely on the compiler to cast my objects to a type. Its a good practice to specify the type...

Comment: I was not disagreeing.  `For Each row...` *might* be the problem; `row("SelfRating")` *definitely* will cause the error but wasnt mentioned.